# Избыточность в форме заявки на подключение к Виду сведений СМЭВ 3.Х

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Есть [форма заявки](https://smev3.gosuslugi.ru/portal/api/files/3_%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%20%D0%92%D0%A1%20%D0%B2%20%D0%A1%D0%9C%D0%AD%D0%92%203%20(%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%92%D0%A1).doc) (указана ниже). Считаю фразу, выделенной курсивом (*на предоставление доступа к Виду сведений*), избыточной, так как заглавие со следующим текстом читаются как одно предложение. Или все-таки я не прав?

> ### ЗАЯВКА *на предоставление доступа к Виду сведений* (в качестве потребителя ВС)
>
> _______________________________ [здесь указывается полное наименование Участника информационного взаимодействия в СМЭВ, краткое наименование Участника, мнемоника Участника]
>
> *на предоставление доступа к Виду сведений* единой системы
>   межведомственного электронного взаимодействия
>
> ________________________________                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            [здесь указывается полное наименование информационной системы Потребителя, краткое наименование ИС, мнемоника ИС] в продуктивной среде СМЭВ 3.хх.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что именно тут избыточно. Текст более или менее читаем, хотя непосвященным человеком воспринимается с трудом. Тавтологии не наблюдается. Возможно вам стоит просто дать свой вариант - для сравнения. Тогда, возможно, что-то прояснится.

Answer (score 1):

Надо учесть, что т. н. пустографку — от руки или в электронном виде — заполняют сплошь в именительном падеже. Об эту особенность документа разбиваются все предположения о получении на выходе стройного предложения.